# Sonarqube integration into private repo on gitlab.com

Tags: java, docker, gradle, sonarqube, gitlab-ci

I'd like to add sonarqube to the CI so i and my team can see whether our code quality is good enough.

I've setup a Sonarqube image in gitlab registry, and tried to intergrate it into the current buildscript.

```
build:
    stage: build
    script: gradle --build-cache assemble --debug
    cache:
        key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
        policy: push
        paths:
            - build
            - .gradle
        dependencies: []

src_check:
    services: 
        - registry.gitlab.com/zerra/zerra/sonarqube:latest
    stage: src_check
    script:
        - echo scanning code quality...
        - gradle sonarqube
```

I get an error `SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000] can not be reached` though i expected adding the registry to the serviced would run the server.

What can I do to get this working? (preferably without having to host a local gitlab version)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the syntax / behaviour of the GitLab CI services definition that you provided there, but assuming that the container starts properly, I think you have to access it under `sonarqube:9000` instead of `localhost:9000`.

The SonarQube container gets linked to the container running the build, and you can reach it via a hostname that is identical to the container name.

At least this is how I interpret the manual here:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#how-services-are-linked-to-the-job

Comment: so i tried this, thanks by the way, but i get this error now `SonarQube server [http://sonarqube:9000] can not be reached`, it looks like sonarqube still isn't found, should i make it 'http://registry.gitlab.com:9000/path/to/registry' ?

Comment: According to the docs, it should be the name of the image, in this case `sonarqube`.

Comment: `SonarQube server [http://sonarqube:9000] can not be reached` when i use `http://sonarqube:9000` what am i doing wrong?